# Design a generic interface to connect to variety of database types

Tags: c#, .net, odbc, oledb

I need to create a service that would be able to

- Get data from a table in defined format from all specified connection strings.
- Connect to variety of databases types.
- I imagined it would look like this

  interface IDataConnectorModule
  {
  Model PullData()
  }
  All I need to do when I'll support new database type to implement the interface for new class lets say, OracleConnector, MySQLConnector,... and then use them in runtime to retrieve data.
- What is the best API's to achieve this? Taking the performance into consideration.
- ODBC, OLE DB or whatever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which database you are connecting you should use different API.
For Sql Server, juste use the SQLConnection with SQL Adapter. It is the fastest for SQL Server.
I have never used ODP.Net but as it is developped by Oracle I would use this one for querying Oracle Database.

ODBC and OLEdb both adds a layer that is going to slow your queries. So use as much "specialized" connectors to your database. This will be more efficient.

Comment: At the end I decided to use the Factory DP. And will implement class for each database provider.
And working providers will be configurable.